# Dialogflow : Getting in an array all document IDs of a firestore collection (javascript node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

**I have been trying to retrieve all documents IDs from my firestore collection.**

Eg. if there are two documents in my collection, i would like to get an array with all the document IDs in the collection.
**ie: var myArray = ['HhYaTvok4qJaIAVI9R0','2AO4RbZ6K5Db4q3OSqi'];**

I have been trying to use some pieces of code from the firestore documentation (https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/9ae3a00985b53025fdc82716046882af71b6009d/firestore/main/index.js#L622-L627).

But it does not retrieve anything in the conversation flow

Below my code in index.js (inline editor).

```js
// The function to get documents ids
const arraymaker = (db) => {
  let platformRef = db.collection('quiz');
    let all_doc = platformRef.get();
    return all_doc
      .then(snapshot => {
        var myArray =[];
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            myArray.push(doc.id);   
          });
        })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
  };

// database retrieve
 app.intent('Read Random Quizz', (conv) => {
   // Trying to get Data from firestone DB,
    //var myArray = ['HhYaTvok4qJaIAVI9dR0','2AO4RbZ6K5Db4q3OS7qi'];
    var myArray = arraymaker(db);
    var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    var platformRef = db.collection("quiz").doc(rand);
    return platformRef.get()
             .then( snap => {
               var dat = "";
               var answ = "";
                 if (snap.exists) {
                   dat =  snap.data().question;
                   answ =  snap.data().answer;
                 }
               // This is the response for Actions on Google
                reply(conv,`The question is ${dat} and the answer is ${answ}`);
            })
            .catch( err => {
              console.log("error...", err);
            });
 });
```

I think the problem comes from :

```js
var myArray = arraymaker(db);
```

It just does not return myArray with all the doc ids.

When i run just the function separatly, i can see an firestore appending all the id in an array.But just in the firestore log. It does not return the final myArray  not in the conversation flow.

Comment: You've shown code that *does* work. Can you update your question to show some of the code that *doesn't*? Fetching just one document is different than fetching all, or a list of all, and dealing with those in your Intent is slightly different as well.

Comment: Thank you Prisoner! i just updated the question

Comment: You have to return all_doc in sec example,

Comment: Thanks Yasser Mas, it helped a lot. I am still having some issues aith returning the final array. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return all_doc in sec example. app.intent have to return a promise like first example, and you are not returning anything inside it in second example.

Besides you are overriding myArray with console.log !! and calling reply with each doc, I am not familiar with firestore but I think you have to call reply after for each and change overriding myArray

```
var myArray ="";
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      myArray += doc.id;           
    });
 reply(conv,`Your list of IDs is ${myArray}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this, and this seems to work. Initially, what i wanted was to retrieve a random document, so i am pasting the solution i found. As mentionned, i am a noob in javascript, and this is probably a very bad code. So any suggestions on how to improve this would be higly welcomed.

```
var GlobalVariable;

// The function to get documents ids in an array called GlobalVariable
const arraymaker = () => {
  let platformRef = db.collection('quiz');
    let all_doc = platformRef.get();
    return all_doc
      .then(snapshot => {
        var myArray =[];
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            myArray.push(doc.id);
      GlobalVariable= myArray;       
          });
        })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
  };


// database retrieve
 app.intent('Read Random Quizz', (conv) => {
    arraymaker(); // restart function to get all the IDs in an array
    // take a random ID and read the document   
    var rand = GlobalVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * GlobalVariable.length)];
    var platformRef = db.collection("quiz").doc(rand);
    return platformRef.get()
             .then( snap => {
               var dat = "";
               var answ = "";
                 if (snap.exists) {
                   dat =  snap.data().question;
                   answ =  snap.data().answer;
                 }
               // This is the response for Actions on Google
                reply(conv,`The question is ${dat} and the answer is ${answ}`);
            })
            .catch( err => {
              console.log("error...", err);
            });
 });
```